# Consider the following function ρ (f) on W1,2[0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Consider the following function on $W^{1,2}[0,1]$: 
$$\rho (f) =|f(0)|+\int_0^1|f′| .$$

i) Show that $\rho$ is a norm on $W^{1,2}[0,1]$ equivalent to the standard norm.

ii) Find constants $c$ and $C$ such that $c\rho (f) \le \| f \|_{W^{1,2}[0,1]}\le C\rho(f)$.

For part i) I want to use the theorem:

|u|<sub>W<sup>k,p</sup>[$\Omega$]</sub>=($\Sigma$<sub>|$\alpha$|=k</sub>||D<sup>$\alpha$</sup>u||<sup>p</sup><sub>L<sup>p</sup>[$\Omega$]</sub>+$\rho$(u)<sup>p</sup>)<sup>1/p</sup>

but I am not sure exactly what to plug in where. I think I want to substitute my original $\rho$(f) equation in for u but am not sure what the $\rho$ in the theorem implies. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the definition of $\rho (u)$ in the case of $W^{k,p}$ functions?